# Trying to write Python to request API from 'nlm.nih.gov'

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I am trying to run my csv data thru "https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/interaction" to identify any drug interactions using python. What else do I need in order to have the program be ready?

I got 200 when print status_code is that mean my code is up and ready?

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/interaction")
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: 200 is `HTTP OK`, yes!

Comment: What's the question? Read about the API you want to use. Most APIs will tell you how to use them.

Comment: this is the page about the API https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/InteractionAPIREST.html . And it does not show any documentation on how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you'd hit this API, using [`requests`](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/) and the details in [their example](https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/InteractionAPIREST.html):

```
import requests

uri = "https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/interaction/interaction.json"
params = {'rxcui': 341248}

r = requests.get(uri, params)
```

Now you can check that `r.status_code` is 200, and get at the result of the request. For example:

```
r.json()
```

As you may realize, this returns a Python dictionary.

The general idea is that `requsts.get()` takes the base URL, followed by the query parameters, given as a dictionary. What you get back depends on the API endpoint you're querying, and/or on the parameters. In this, it's giving you JSON. Others might give you text (see `r.text` for this representation), or bytes (`r.content`).